# preload image with jquery of window onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

it's a gif that within window onload, how to preload it with jquery? It has a bit of lag because of the size..

It seem I have to switch to css preloader instead of gif?

Comment: google will help you...

Comment: 5 person couldn't get to answer this voted down so far..

Answer (score 0):

You can preload images in javascript in your window.onload method. Hide it before, using css and when the image loads (in the onload image event), show it.

```
 .hide { display: none; } 
 .show { display: block; } 

 var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
 img.src = 'myCoolGiff.gif'; 
 img.addEventListener("load", function() {   
   // execute drawImage    
   this.style.className = "show";  
 },false);
```